# breaking down list comprehension in python

Tags: python

I have this one line comprehension and am trying to break it down to understand it:

```
 units = dict((s, [u for u in unitlist if s in u]) for s in boxes)
```

So far I have come up with this but it doesn't give the same output:

```
u = []
for s in boxes:
    for u in unitlist:
        if s in u:
            u.append(u)
            units = dict(u)
```

please advise, and also please guide me to any place i can understand how to switch between the two better. I find it easier to understand code without the one liners.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Original expression with list comprehension:

```
units = dict((s, [u for u in unitlist if s in u]) for s in boxes)
```

Classical reproduction:

```
units = {}

for s in boxes:
    values = []
    for u in unitlist:
        if s in u:
            values.append(u)

    units[s] = values
```

Your original expression says "make a `dict()` composed of `key, value` pairs with `s` as `key` and a sublist of unitlist as `value`"

Your expression also says there is a condition: although all `s in boxes` will be found as keys in your `units` dict, the associated values will be equal or a sublist of `u`.

Comment: Thanks you helped me a lot with that, I've done it with other list comprehensions now.